# How to use PreferenceFragment and still support Android 2.3

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, preferenceactivity, preferencefragment

I'm currently migrating my preferences to the preferenceFragment class with headers.

I still want to support Android Versions < 3.0 so I have to use a legacy xml file as well. (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html#BackCompatHeaders)

My problem is now that I have to disable some preference on runtime, set summaries etc. How do I do this now without writing the code 2 times?

So my preferenceActivity is looking like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {      
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  String action = getIntent().getAction();
  if (action != null) {
    if (action.equals(ACTION_TEST)) {
      addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences_push_sms);
      // How do I call changePreferences()?
    }
  }

  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preference_headers_legacy);
  }
}

@Override
public void onBuildHeaders(List<Header> target) {
  loadHeadersFromResource(R.xml.preference_headers, target);
}

public static class SettingsFragmentTest extends PreferenceFragment {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);

  changePreferences();
}

public void changePreferences() {
  CheckBoxPreference preference = (CheckBoxPreference) findPreference("pref_toggle");
  preference.setChecked(condition()));
  [...]
}
```

How can I call `changePreferences()` for Android 2.3? I can't access it from `PreferenceActivity.onCreate()`.

If I make `changePreferences()` static I'm not able to use findPreference anymore. What is the best way to still support Android 2.3 with `PrefernceFragment`? Where should I put methods to alter the preferences at runtime?

Comment: "How can I call changePreferences() for Android 2.3?" -- make it static and take a `CheckBoxPreference` as a parameter, perhaps.

Comment: I cant just pass CheckBoxPreference as a parameter.. I have to edit several checkboxes, listviews, etc..

Comment: Then pass a `HashMap<String,Preference>` that contains all the preferences.